# How to open .rb file by RubyMine from error message in iTerm2

Tags: macos, rubymine, iterm

I'm using `iTerm2` and `RubyMine` in `Mavericks`.

In `iTerm` I can open a file from error message by clicking file name with `Command` key.

But somehow the `.rb` file is opend `SublimeText`.

I changed association of the file to RubyMine in Finder.

(Select a `.rb` file` -> Open Menu -> Open File with: RubyMine -> All type of files are opend same Application)

But it seems to be valid only in Finder.

How can I configure so that I can open `.rb` file by RubyMine from iTerm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Advanced.

Under Semantic History

Change to `Run command...` with the value `open \1`

Comment: Thanks, I could open the file by `RubyMine`, the line is not reflected though. I'll send a feature request to `RubyMine` community.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open the file on the given line, you can use the second parameter in Semantic History settings of iTerm2. The line number should be passed as the `--line` parameter to rubymine:

```
path_to_rubymine --line \2 \1
```

See [Rubymine](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.1/working-with-rubymine-features-from-command-line.html) and [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-preferences.html) help for more info.

Comment: This works for me with RubyMine 8 on OS X Yosemite. I entered `/usr/local/bin/mine \1 --line \2` with 'Run command..' selected. Sometimes RubyMine window is being active (brought to front) but most of times it stays behind though.